# Generate JPA compatible POJO's from DB2 schema (similar to middlegen+hbm2java)?

Tags: java, jpa, db2, hbm2java

I want to automatically generate POJO's corresponding to a set of DB/2 tables to test if JPA will work well for a new application.

In ancient history I used middlegen to create Hibernate mappings which then hbm2java could create POJOs from, and searching mostly revealed outdated information.  I was wondering if middlegen is still the tool to use (and if so, where is its current homepage) even for JPA, or if a new toolset has arisen for JPA.

So, how do I generate POJO's from my DB/2 schema?

Answer (score 0):

I used [Dali](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/) to automatically generate pojo entities from the database schema. Not sure how, or even if, it works programmatically though ...